# Issue with fast disapearing menu items in Wordpress site?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

Hi i have one issue with my [personal site](http://touchdowner.cz/digitalni-produkty/), that dont know how to fix. i use theme [Remix](http://codevz.com/demo/remix/)

The issue is that my main menu is showing too fast submenus and disapearing, so user is unable to select some submenu. I see this CSS, but changing things inside didnt changed something.. On Remix demo site all is working properly as should be.

```
.sf-menu li:hover > a, .sf-menu li > a:hover, .sf-menu > .selectedLava > a, 
.page-template-page-onepage .sf-menu li.current a {
border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: As I see in this css there's only border rule. There should be some kind of js to control display or another css rule

Comment: Weird.. it works fine on my machine. Really, I entered your site and everything looks fine with the menu

Comment: Strange.. That issue is persist only on Google Chrome. On Firefox is Just ok. Only that white border, that need to remove, but dont know what is that class. Do you know why is only affecting on Google Chrome.?